# What`s wrong with qt 4.5.0 integration with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, qt4

I downloaded and installed qt evaluation for vs2008 and expect it to be integrated with VS, but it is not. It is trial 30 days commercial license. What`s wrong with it or may be I got it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio integration is a separate download:
http://www.qtsoftware.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in

Comment: thanks a lot! Is it free or commercial? I didn`t get it from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you only install Qt or also the Visual Studio Integration, which is a separate download?

Comment: the thing is - actually, I don`t know. can you please give any links? what I installed is qt windows evaluation vs2008?

Comment: No, I can't. We have a guy here that does the commercial Qt downloads for us, I just use them ;) The file is named qt-vsintegration-1.4.3.exe (the version number does not correspond to Qt versions). I don't know if it is available for evaluation.